# I would like to block access to all http

Tags: ssh, https

On a Linux system, I need to block outbound access to all http and https traffic except to the web server 192.168.1.253. The system should also block all incoming traffic except ssh.

How would I configure this?

Comment: "_block access to all http and https traffic_" is that outbound from the system? How would you detect HTTP or HTTPS traffic outbound to, say, port 8080?

Comment: I would like  to block access to all http and https traffic except to the web server 192.168.1.253 in a linux machine

Comment: What Linux system are you using? (Different distributions use different tools for managing firewall rules.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

option 1: unplug the system

option 2: use **tcp_wrappers**

edit `/etc/hosts.allow` to have

```
# allow all ssh traffic
SSHD : ALL : ALLOW

# allow specific http
HTTP: 192.168.1.253/255.255.255.0

# allow specific https
HTTPS: 192.168.1.253/255.255.255.0
```

edit `/etc/hosts.deny` to have

```
# have console access to your system before putting this in hosts.deny
# you have been warned

# this will disable all traffic, and require explicit definition in hosts.allow for **anything** to work

ALL : ALL
```

**man tcpd** for more information.

Comment: what about the port for http and https? is there a way with “iptables'

Comment: Ron I think (although it's still not entirely clear) that the OP wants to block _outbound_ access to tcp/80 and tcp/443.

Comment: fyi: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/Deprecate_TCP_wrappers